# Infragistics WPF / Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, pdf, infragistics

I've been going around and around in circles looking at a mixture of half arsed demos and hugely outdated "support articles" on the Infragistics site.  Questions have sat unanswered for days on the Reporting forum on their site ... time I broke out and came to SO for some real help!

I have access to the Infragistics Ultimate collection for my current project so I've get everything to hand.  I've been having real issues looking into getting PDFs created.  I have some pretty complex XamDataGrids and XamDataCharts to get rendered out to PDF/Excel.

Excel appears to be very well catered for and I've already used the engine to import data and it looks like support for going back to Excel is fairly well documented.

The real issue is getting PDFs created.

I've now just discovered an entire WPF PDF Library that I've not seen mentioned in any docs or samples and I'm hoping someone here can shed some light on the topic.  Everything in the DLL is internal however, anyone know how to use this?

If anyone has any demo code or pointers that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Listing off the technologies you use is not a proper title.  That information belongs in tags.

Comment: Shame about Infragistics, but your experience is not unique. You can read about others' experience in the questions tagged infragistics.

Comment: cadrell0, I only just noticed I left it like that.  Useless title ... sorry

Comment: Can you tell me the name of this misterious library/technology you have found in Infragistics Ultimate Collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Documents engine from NetAdvantage for Windows Forms or NetAdvantage for ASP.NET to create your PDF file.  The following blog is a good walk through for using the Documents engine:

http://community.infragistics.com/blogs/sung_kim/archive/2009/02/18/publishing-dynamic-files-pdf-xps-creation-using-the-infragistics-document-library.aspx